# Can I apply for a D type visa for Germany when I already have a D type visa for italy?

Tags: germany, student-visa, italy

When I learned that I was accepted from a university in Italy for the master's program, I applied for an long term student visa for Italy and it was approved. Then I learned that I was accepted to a university in Germany and I want to apply for a long term student visa for Germany because I want to do a master's degree in that University. My questions are:

Will I get rejected when I apply to student visa for Germany because I have a student visa for Italy?

What happens to my approved italy visa when I apply for a long term student visa for Germany?

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to a **Schengen Visa** (Type C), it doesn't matter if you have more that one **National Visa** (Type D).

Since you cannot use an Italian National visa to reside and attend a university in Germany, you **must** apply for a German National visa.

The Italian National visa will at some point expire without being used.